# Is there any reward for gaining all the collectibles in Valiant Hearts: The Great War?

Tags: valiant-hearts

I love this game, and have explored it almost all the way, and I have all of the collectibles... except one. I want to know if there is any reward for finding all the collectibles in this particular game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/valiant-hearts-great-war-historical-items-collectibles-guide/)  you'll get a **They'll all be remembered** trophy or achievement. [Here's](http://www.trueachievements.com/Valiant-Hearts-The-Great-War/achievements.htm) a full list of achievements I suppose.